# Why are my code not working ?.This a code to check whether a number is a palindrome or not for positive number

Tags: java, palindrome

import java.util.Scanner;
public class CheckPalindrome3 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your number :");
    String num = input.nextLine();
    String arr = "";
    for(int i = num.length() - 1 ; i >= 0;i--)
    {
    
        arr = arr + num.charAt(i);
    }
System.out.println(arr+"\n"+num);
    if(arr == num) {
        System.out.println("Yes that's a Palindrome !!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No that's not a Palindrome !!");
    }

}
```

}

When I put 121 it printed out No thats not a palindrome but arr is the same as num

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the test `arr == num`. For strings, `==` tests whether the two strings have the same address in memory (which often is not true, even if the strings look the same). Use `arr.equals(num)` instead. That will test if all of the characters in `arr` are the same as those in `num`.